# Android Studio Error : No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_behavior' in package 'com.example.parthp.myapplication'

Tags: android

I am trying a tutorial from this link : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

When I edited xml code as described in tutorial then it started showing error (that I've mentioned in the title of this question).

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_my">
```

I think there is something wrong with tools:showIn="@layout/activity_my" because when i remove this everything work ok.

PS:I am newbie to android.

Comment: post full xml code...

Comment: This is full xml code except the termination tag </LinearLayout>.

Comment: inside  LinearLayout nothing you added ??

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya It still shows error

Comment: have any xml name `activity_my` ?? If not, you need to create .

Comment: which Android  studio Version are you using. ?

Comment: check my answer and add layout and something in it

Comment: @AndoMasahashi : dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
}

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya : yes under layout there is activity_my.xml

Comment: use `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'`

Comment: use `compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I just changed tools:showIn="@layout/activity_my" with tools:showIn="@layout/activity_my.xml" and it works is it oK ???

Answer (score 0):

You will missing the `activity_my` in the layout folder includes the `content_my.xml` file

A simple code for content_my.xml will be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I do have activitiy_my in layout folder.

Comment: can you post the logcat

Comment: I just changed tools:showIn="@layout/activity_my" with tools:showIn="@layout/activity_my.xml" and it works is it oK ???

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the `activity_my.xml` file.

In the last line of your code, you're telling the compiler that the xml layout (that you've described in your question) should be shown in `activity_my.xml` file.

Create the `activity_my.xml` file and include this layout into that file.

The file might look something like:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`content_main` would be the name of the file whose xml code you've posted in the question.

Comment: I just changed tools:showIn="@layout/activity_my" with tools:showIn="@layout/activity_my.xml" and it works is it oK ???

Comment: Yeah, it's fine. In `developers.android.com`, you'll get more of such situations where you'll get similar errors. And most of them will be resolved if you follow the tutorials to the end.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed

```
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_my"
```

to

```
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_my.xml"
```

and it now works.